# tornado asynchttpclient.fetch using post return TypeError

Tags: python, tornado, tornado-motor

I use Tornado **AsynchHTTPClient().fetch(url, method="POST",body=body,headers=headers)** with coroutine,but an error thrown:

> TypeError: Expected bytes, unicode, or None; got type 'int'

```
    @gen.coroutine
    def do_post(self, url, data):
        self.checksum_builder()
        headers = {
            'AppKey': self.app_key,
            'Nonce': self.nonce,
            'CurTime': self.current_time,
            'CheckSum': self.checksum,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
        }
        postdata = data
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        print urllib.urlencode(postdata)
        response = yield http_client.fetch(url, method='POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(postdata))
        print response.error
        raise gen.Return(response)

    @gen.coroutine
    def create_nim_id(self, accid,  name='', props='', icon='', token=''):
        data = dict({
                'accid':accid,
                'name':name,
                'props':props,
                'icon':icon,
                'token':token
            })
        response = yield self.do_post(self.create_nim_id_url, data)
        raise gen.Return(response)




    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        result = yield netease_im_api.NeteaseAPI().create_nim_id(accid='moonmoonbird1',icon='2',props='321',token='adsadsadsadsd', name='hello')
        print(result)
```

> [E 160504 20:32:39 web:1524] Uncaught exception GET
>   /card/8/76d27dfa11cf11e69d86a45e60dcaf9d (127.0.0.1)
>       HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8000', method='GET', uri='/card/8/76d27dfa11cf11e69d86a45e60dcaf9d',
>   version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Host':
>   '127.0.0.1:8000', 'Cookie':
>   '_xsrf=2|1d0561f1|3c717ed824bff16dc8f804b0a7c990ca|1462268491',
>   'Connection': 'close', 'User-Agent': 'Paw/2.2.9 (Macintosh; OS
>   X/10.11.2) GCDHTTPRequest'})
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py",
>   line 1445, in _execute
>           result = yield result
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 1008, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py",
>   line 232, in result
>           raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 1014, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/kuolie/account/utils.py", line
>   70, in wrapper
>           ret = yield ret
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 1008, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py",
>   line 232, in result
>           raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 1014, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/kuolie/wall/handlers.py", line
>   129, in get
>           result = yield netease_im_api.NeteaseAPI().create_nim_id(accid='moonmoonbird1',icon='2',props='321',token='adsadsadsadsd',
>   name='hello')
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 1008, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py",
>   line 232, in result
>           raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 1014, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/kuolie/neteaseim/netease_im_api.py",
>   line 84, in create_nim_id
>           response = yield self.do_post(self.create_nim_id_url, data)
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 1008, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py",
>   line 232, in result
>           raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 1014, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/kuolie/neteaseim/netease_im_api.py",
>   line 60, in do_post
>           response = yield http_client.fetch(url, method='POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(postdata))
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 1008, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "/Users/moonmoonbird/Documents/kuolie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py",
>   line 232, in result
>           raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>         File "", line 3, in raise_exc_info
>       TypeError: Expected bytes, unicode, or None; got type int

I cant find where i am wrong, can someone help me,thanks in advance.

Comment: I think `http_client.fetch` failed without a valid response.

Comment: i found the problem, that **'CurTime': self.current_time** should be 'CurTime': str(self.current_time), the current_time is type of int,which should be str